# Using stacks and static arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I am trying to implement a class called SharingStacks, that implements two stacks Stack a and Stack b, this class contains all the functions of a single stack class (i.e push, pop, is empty etc..) except that this class contains TWO Stacks sharing ONE static array.

I have it going pop and push etc.. But I need to figure out a way to ensure that when I push on Stack I don't override the other Stack. i.e if S[4] contains Stack a element, I couldn't push with Stack b and override. I'm trying to think about logically how to do this..But I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: A straightforward solution - duplicate every method: pushA and pushB, popA and popB... There are neater options, but that one works without changing your current approach.

Comment: @boisvert do you mean duplicate them in the struct?

Answer (score 0):

you need two more indexes, the end of stack a and the end of stack b. When you push on either stack make sure that you dont tread on the end of the other stack. Then after the push you increment the end index

Comment: I made some adjustments to my functions and provided details so hopefully you see where I am stuck

Comment: 'tread' means that stack a doesn't try to write into the end of stack b and vice versa

Comment: Do you mean like adding counters i, j and every time I push either stack to increment those, but before doing that i should check to make sure that `i!=j`?

Comment: you need a permanent counter that points to the end of each stack. StackEndA, StackEndB. When the stacks are empty these are the same as StackAStart and StackBStart. Just make sure that StackAEnd < StackB end and return an error if it look like that is going to happen